# Using L'hopital's rule find $\lim_{x{\to 0}}\frac{\int_0^{2x}\ln(1+t)dt}{\int_{x^4}^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Using L'hopital's rule find

$$\lim_{x{\to 0}}\frac{\int_0^{2x}\ln(1+t)dt}{\int_{x^4}^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt}$$

I want first to know what form this is.

${\int_0^{2x}\ln(1+t)dt} = \lim_{x\to0}\int_0^{2x}\ln(1+t)dt$ how rigorously show that this is $0$ and for denominator too.

My thoughts are that as $x\to 0$ we get $\int_0^{x\to0}\ln(1+t)dt$ so for every $\epsilon$,   $t<\epsilon$ and becomes $\int_0 ^{x\to0} 0$ but can't say this is real analysis proof or not.

Comment: Give names to things: $$F(x)=\int_0^x\ln(1+t)\,\mathrm dt,\qquad G(x):=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}t\,\mathrm dt.$$
You are looking at $\enspace\displaystyle\frac{F(2x)}{G(x^2)-G(x^4)}$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x) = \int_0^{2x}\ln(1 + t)\,dt$ is a continuous function. It follows that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0),
$$
so that the limit of the numerator is zero. The denominator can be shown to approach zero similarly.

Comment: @BenGrossmann +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x) = \int_0^{2x}\ln(1 + t)\,dt$ is a continuous function. It follows that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0) = \int_0^0 \ln(1 + t) \,dt = 0,
$$
which is to say that the limit of the numerator is zero. The denominator can be shown to approach zero similarly.

Answer (score 0):

For $t>0$, $\vert \ln(1+t) \vert \leqslant 1$ for $\vert t\vert<1/2$. It follows that for $x<1/4$ $$ \bigg \vert \int_0^{2x} \ln (1+t) \, dt  \bigg \vert \leqslant  \int_0^{2x} \big \vert \ln (1+t) \big \vert \, dt   \leqslant \int_0^{2x}  \, dt = 2x \to 0 $$ as $x\to 0$.

Using that $\vert \sin t \vert  \leqslant t$ for $t>0$ can you do the other integral?

Answer (score 0):

We have,
$$\displaystyle\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2x}\,ln(1+t)\,dt}{\displaystyle\int_{x^4}^{x^2}\,\dfrac{sin(t)}{t}\,dt}}$$

Please note that
$$\displaystyle\mathtt{\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\,h(t)\,dt\right)=h\left(g(x)\right)\cdot\,g^{\prime}(x)-h\left(f(x)\right)\cdot\,f^{\prime}(x)}$$

So, using L'hopital's rule,$$\displaystyle=\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{2x}\,ln(1+t)\,dt}{\displaystyle\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{x^4}^{x^2}\,\dfrac{sin(t)}{t}\,dt}}$$

$$\displaystyle=\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{ln(1+2x)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x)-0}{\dfrac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2)-\dfrac{sin(x^4)}{x^4}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^4)}}$$

$$\displaystyle=\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{2\,ln(1+2x)}{\dfrac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}\cdot2x-\dfrac{sin(x^4)}{x^4}\cdot4\,x^3}}$$

$$\displaystyle=\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{2\,ln(1+2x)}{2x\left\{\dfrac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}-\dfrac{sin(x^4)}{x^4}\cdot2\,x^2\right\}}}$$

$$\displaystyle=\mathsf{\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{2\,\dfrac{ln(1+2x)}{2x}}{\dfrac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}-\dfrac{sin(x^4)}{x^4}\cdot2\,x^2}}$$

$$=\mathsf{\dfrac{\displaystyle2\,\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{ln(1+2x)}{2x}}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}-\lim_{x\to\,0}\dfrac{sin(x^4)}{x^4}\cdot\lim_{x\to\,0}2\,x^2}}$$

$$=\mathsf{\dfrac{2\cdot1}{1-1\cdot0}}$$

$$=\mathsf{\dfrac{2}{1-0}}$$

$$=\mathsf{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{l}
L:=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\displaystyle  \frac{\int_{0}^{2 x} \ln (1+t) d t}{\int_{x^{4}}^{x^{2}} \frac{\sin t}{t} d t}\quad \left(\frac{0}{0}\right)\\
\displaystyle \quad =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2 \ln (1+2 x)}{\frac{\sin \left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}} \cdot(2 x)-\frac{\sin \left(x^{4}\right)}{x^{4}}\left(4 x^{3}\right)} \quad \text { (L'Hospital and Chain Rule)}\\
\displaystyle \quad =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x \ln (1+2 x)}{\sin \left(x^{2}\right)-2 \sin \left(x^{4}\right)}\quad \left(\frac{0}{0}\right)\\
\displaystyle \quad =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{2 x}{1+2 x}+\ln (1+2 x)}{2 x \cos \left(x^{2}\right)-8 x^{3} \cos \left(x^{4}\right)}\quad \text{(L’Hospital Rule)}\\
\displaystyle \quad =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{2}{1+2 x}+\frac{\ln (1+2 x)}{x}}{2 \cos \left(x^{2}\right)-8 x^{2} \cos \left(x^{4}\right)}\\
\because \displaystyle \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln (1+2 x)}{x}=\displaystyle \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{2}{1+2 x}}{1}=2\\
\therefore \quad \displaystyle  L=\frac{2+2}{2-0}=2
\end{array}